# How to include a figure in latex main body

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a figure like this which has 2 sub-figures; how to include this in my other main document? Where I can use \input{figure_name} and this figure is shown in my parent document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    trig format=rad,    % <---
                    domain=0:1,         % <---
                    samples=501,        % <---
                    no marks]           % <---
                \addplot {sin(10*x};
                
                \legend{$\sin(10x)$}
                \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    trig format=rad,    % <---
                    domain=0:1,         % <---
                    samples=501,        % <---
                    no marks]           % <---
                \addplot {sin(100*x};
               
                \legend{$\sin(100x)$}
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Increasing oscillatory function}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can not input a document  just copy from begin{figure} to the other document

Comment: Quite simple: iolution from it `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `\end{tikzpiczure}` which you got in answer to your previous question, insert into ˛subfigure˛environment. What is here a problem?

Comment: @Zarko there are 2` \begin{tikzpicture}` How to import both such that they stay at place?

Comment: each in own `subfigure`as is done in my answer. Do you check it?

Comment: @Zarko What to write in the main body where I want to insert this figure: I am writting; 

 \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \input{figs/FIG_10.tikz} 
            \caption{Functions used to plot the previous plot}
            \label{fig:EW}
\end{figure}

Comment: Please see my answer. It contain complete small document, that proposed solution, which start with `\begi{figure}` and end with `\end{figure}`. Insert this in your document. Let me repeat, please consider my comment below my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

I assume, that both images have the same `axis` settings, therefore it can be write in local `\pgfplotsset` and by this make figure code a bit shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\pgfplotsset{% common settings for both images
    width=\linewidth,
    scale only axis,
    trig format=rad,    % <---
    domain=0:pi/2,      % <---
    samples=501,        % <---
    no marks,           % <---
% added,˛
    every axis plot post/.append style={semithick},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize,
                  cells={anchor=west}}
            }

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {sin(10*x};
\addplot {sin(25*x)};
\addplot {sin(50*x)};

\legend{$\sin(10x)$,$\sin(25x)$,$\sin(50x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {sin(100*x)};
\addplot {sin(150*x))};
\addplot {sin(200*x))};

\legend{$\sin(100x)$,$\sin(150x)$,$\sin(200x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Increasing oscillatory function}
\label{fig:??}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, if you have images in parallel, they are at given page layout quite narrower and consequently less clear. To improve visibiliti of diagrams, you have several options:

- change page layout with enlarge `\textwidth`
- put one image above other
- reduce domain at second image

**Addendum:**

- I wonder why your subfigures hasn't captions
- if they are not desired, you may consider to use `groupplot` instead of `subfigures`
- In MWE below, is considered:

  - reduced waves domain for second images
  - increased `\textwidth` by use of the `geometry` package
  - for quantities in subfigure captions is used ˙siunnitx` packageČ

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}   % for setting page layout

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\pgfplotsset{% common settings for both images
    width=0.8\linewidth,
    scale only axis,
    enlargelimits = 0.05,
    trig format=rad,     
    samples=801,         
    no marks,            
% added, for better diagram formating
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, zerofill, fixed},
    every axis plot post/.append style={semithick},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize,
                  cells={anchor=west}}
            }

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=0:1,      % <---
            ]
\addplot {sin(10*x};
\addplot {sin(25*x)};
\addplot {sin(50*x)};

\legend{$\sin(10x)$,$\sin(25x)$,$\sin(50x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinus waves on domain \qtyrange{0}{1}{\radian}.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=0:0.25,      % <---
            ]
\addplot {sin(100*x)};
\addplot {sin(150*x)};
\addplot {sin(200*x)};

\legend{$\sin(100x)$,$\sin(150x)$,$\sin(200x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinus waves on domain \qtyrange{0}{0.25}{\radian}.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Increasing oscillatory function}
\label{fig:??}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}   % for setting page layout

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\pgfplotsset{% common settings for both images
    width=0.8\linewidth,
    scale only axis,
    enlargelimits = 0.05,
    trig format=rad,    % <---
    samples=801,        % <---
    no marks,           % <---
% added,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, zerofill, fixed},
    every axis plot post/.append style={semithick},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize,
                  cells={anchor=west}}
            }

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=0:1,      % <---
            ]
\addplot {sin(10*x};
\addplot {sin(25*x)};
\addplot {sin(50*x)};

\legend{$\sin(10x)$,$\sin(25x)$,$\sin(50x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinus waves on domain \qtyrange{0}{1}{\radian}.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=0:0.25,      % <---
            ]
\addplot {sin(100*x)};
\addplot {sin(150*x)};
\addplot {sin(200*x)};

\legend{$\sin(100x)$,$\sin(150x)$,$\sin(200x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinus waves on domain \qtyrange{0}{0.25}{\radian}.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Increasing oscillatory function}
\label{fig:??}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to input this in my main.tex document? I am storing this whole figure in Fig10.tikz

Comment: I suggest you to read some introductory text about LaTeX. For example 
 https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.  There are explained all basic about use of LaTeX .... **(i)** check if in your document preamble are loaded packages used in my MWE, if not, add missed one.; **(ii)** insert code from `\begin{figure}` to `\end{figure}`  in my answer to your document. That is!

Comment: What to do, if I have the figure in separate .tikz file ? how to import then?

Comment: Sorry,  in comments I can't give you  a short lecture about LaTeX. Im previous my comment is link to introductory text about LaTeX, where is described all what you need to know for you using LaTeX and repeatedly  here. For including files in "main" document are dedicated `include` and `input` macros (command).  Try to use them, see result and if you will stuck in this, ask new question, where show what you try and what is going wrong.